Help Needed with Chosen Plaintext Attack on AES-CTR
I'm working on a cryptanalysis project for my professor, and I need some guidance. The assignment involves implementing one of the following types of attacks on a ciphertext encrypted with a symmetric key algorithm:

Chosen plaintext
Chosen ciphertext

I've implemented AES with CTR mode, and I’m considering using a chosen plaintext attack.
But I don't know how to implement it as I haven't found any practical examples online or in books. Based on theory, I've come up with the following solution:

I send a plaintext of the same length as the ciphertext I want to decrypt to the encryption algorithm.

The resulting ciphertext is XORed with the original plaintext to obtain the keystream.

I can then XOR this keystream with the ciphertext I want to decrypt to get the plaintext.


Unfortunately, I'm not sure if the keystream remains the same for each encryption during a chosen plaintext attack, and I'm not sure if my professor will accept such a solution since the way he described the attacks seemed much more complex.
Does this method seem valid for a chosen plaintext attack? Would this be acceptable as a demonstration for my project? Additionally, is there a specific name for this type of attack within the chosen plaintext category?
Thank you for any insights or feedback you can provide!

You’ve either missed important requirements, or the assignment doesn’t make sense. AES in CTR mode isn’t inherently vulnerable to chosen plaintext attacks. Only if both the nonce and the key are reused, this is when you can decrypt the other plaintext. So is this an assumption the professor made? And are you sure you’re supposed to attack AES in CTR mode as opposed to a cipher that actually is vulnerable to CPA? If you don’t know, it might be a good idea to ask for clarification before doing anything.

XORing the ciphertext with the known plaintext just gives you the encrypted keystream. This by itself isn’t interesting. An attack is only possible if the keystream is reused, or if the cipher itself has problems.

The game and model is here for CPA Is One Time Pad considered Chosen-Plaintext Attack Secure?

Hint 2: Easy explanation of "IND-" security notions?, modify....

@Ja1024 the assignment is free. They can choose the hill cipher for CPA and be done. CTR on the other hand is fine choice to have Ind-CPA but doesn't have Ind-CCAx.

@kelalaka So is there a way to complete this assignment with AES-CTR?

My reading is one of the following types of attacks so if you attack with CCA attacker then you solved your assignment.

@kelalaka So should i just send the ciphertext to the decryption oracle? If not, can you share some information about how to perform a CCA?

You are not allowed the send the original queries, however, you can modify them to your advantage.

No, The keystream won't remain same for every encryption or for every keystream generation as there is a concept of nonces involved which will change for every message sent rather every ciphertext the attacker interrupts, change of nonce will reflect on change of keystream obviously.

That answer applies to chosen plaintext attack against AES-CTR (not coincidentally, AES-CTR is considered secure against chosen plaintext attack). It does not apply to chosen ciphertext attack, where the attacker is assumed to have a decryption oracle, which accepts an arbitrary IV/nonce and allows nonce reuse.
